# Is it legal to publish youtube videos at flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, webview, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to use YouTube videos as part of my apps using YouTube API and web view
I just wonder what are all the issues that I can face

Comment: Youtube is open source and it's pretty easy to play youtube video online. You can use [link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_youtube#-readme-tab-) this for flutter. But you can't download the video.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.youtube.com/static?gl=CA&template=terms .   you must adhere to their TOS rules. And like it or not,  They reserve the right to shut you down at any time they so choose.